# Django LDAP group search Issue

Tags: django, authentication, ldap, ldapauth

I am trying to implement LDAP in Django.
I am able to login using LDAP in Django. But when I am trying to limited access for some particular group, I can not login any more.

Here is my code:

Settings.py

```
  import ldap
  from django_auth_ldap.config import ldapsearch, GroupOfUniqueNamesType, GroupOfNamesType ,LDAPGroupQuery, PosixGroupType 
#(I imported many, as I was trying differently)


AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = 'ldap://ldap.mydomain.de'    
AUTH_LDAP_USER_DN_TEMPLATE = 'uid=%(user)s,ou=user,dc=mydomain,dc=de'

#AUTH_LDAP_START_TLS = True

AUTH_LDAP_BIND_AS_AUTHENTICATING_USER = True
AUTH_LDAP_CACHE_GROUPS = True
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_CACHE_TIMEOUT = 3600
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = "" 
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = "" 
#AUTH_LDAP_FIND_GROUP_PERMS = True #added for group

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail"
}

#ldap
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("cn=My_group_Name, dc=mydomain,dc=de",
                                    ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(objectClass=posixAccount)"
                                    )
#AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = GroupOfNamesType()
AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE = PosixGroupType (name_attr="cn")

AUTH_LDAP_REQUIRE_GROUP = "cn=My_group_Name, dc=mydomain,dc=de"

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
]
```

If I turn off Require_Group, I can login successfully. but if I turn on, error arises. (I am in the group) The log is like

```
search_s('uid=shaondebnath,ou=user,dc=mydomain,dc=de', 0, '(objectClass=*)') returned 1 objects: uid=shaondebnath,ou=user,dc=mydomain,dc=de
Caught LDAPError while authenticating shaondebnath: NO_SUCH_OBJECT({'matched': u'dc=mydomain,dc=de', 'desc': u'No such object'},)
```

The information I Have from my Organization is

```
$ conf ['authtype'] = 'authldap'; 
$ conf ['plugin'] ['authldap'] ['server'] = 'ldap.mydomain.de'; 
$ conf ['plugin'] ['authldap'] ['usertree'] = 'ou = user, dc = mydomain, dc = de'; 
$ conf ['plugin'] ['authldap'] ['userfilter'] = '(& (objectClass = posixAccount) (uid =% {user}))'; 
$ conf ['plugin'] ['authldap'] ['version'] = 3; 
$ conf ['plugin'] ['authldap'] ['mapping'] ['grps'] = array ('memberof' => '/CN=(.+?),/i');
```

Where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

In your AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_SEARCH, it is unlikely that your group has posixAccount as an objectclass -- in which case your group search finds no matching object.

Since you are supplying a fully qualified DN as the search base (the "cn-my_group_name...,dc=de"), you could use the filter "(&(objectClass=*))" which will match any object class.

Alternately, use an LDAP browser (the ldap client utils may be installed on the server, providing ldapsearch) to view the group object to determine what object classes are present on the object. You should see something like groupOfUniqueNames, posixGroup, or group. Use the group object class name in place of posixAccount.